# xml2js not parsing xml retrieved through proxy

Tags: xml, node.js, proxy

I am working on a nodejs app and using xml2js to parse xml files.
When the xml file is local, I have no problems parsing it with xml2js, however, I need to retrieve remote xml files, and I need to connect through a proxy.

This code (reading a local xml file) works:

```
var rundownParser = new xml2js.Parser();
function parseRundown(){
    fs.readFile(rundownFolder + '/' + rundownFile, function(err, data) {
        rundownParser.parseString(data);
    });
}
rundownParser.on('end', function(result) {
    console.log("PARSER ENDED")
});
```

This is my code that retrieves the remote XML file through the proxy:

```
    var rundownParser = new xml2js.Parser();    
    function parseRundown(){
        var options = {
          host: proxyHost,
          port: proxyPort,
          path: mosGatewayPath,
          method: 'GET',
          headers : {
              host: mosGatewayHost
          }
        };

        var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
            res.on('data', function (response) {
                console.log("REMOTE DATA: "+response)
                rundownParser.parseString(response); 
            });
        });
        req.end();
    }
    rundownParser.on('end', function(result) {
        console.log("PARSER ENDED")
});
```

In the code that retrieves the remote file, I see the correct response in the 'data' event. So I know that the connection is working, but after that it just hangs, it never reaches the parsers 'end' event. No errors are thrown.

I would really appreciate any help in pointing out what I am doing incorrect.

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling parseString after response emits 'end'.

e.g.

```
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
    var body;

    res.on('data', function (data) {
        body += data
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
      console.log("REMOTE DATA: "+body)
      rundownParser.parseString(body); 
    });
});
```